# SQL Developer: Stop opening a new worksheet when connecting to schema.

Tags: sqldeveloper

Each time I connect to a schema it opens a new worksheet for that schema. Can I stop it doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes you can.

In **SQLDeveloper 3.2** (and above) navigate to:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences...</kbd> > <kbd>Database</kbd> > <kbd>Worksheet</kbd> > <kbd>Open a Worksheet on connect</kbd>